# How to dynamically replace/hide items in an ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I'm using an ActionBar that displays some MenuItems icon.
What I need, is to be able to replace or Hide some MenuItems when the activity opens.
My problem is that I can't find a way to get a MenuItem reference outside the onCreateOptionsMenu() method...
Any idea on how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) to show/hide menu items in the activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    menu.getItem(0).setVisible(false);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```